# How can I stop my 'roulette style' number picker from lagging?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a roulette style number picker based on this code pen:

https://codepen.io/tim-rayner/pen/QWgjvYx

after replicating this roulette in react, I noticed that the wheel seems to lag behind upon spinning; not always rendering the cards towards the end of the wheel container for a split-second (or seems to be getting ahead of itself), If run the code-pen I am sure you'll be able to reproduce easily with the example provided.

It seems like the animation is too fast for the cards to render in time... Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//setup multiple rows of colours, can also add and remove while spinning but overall this is 
easier.
initWheel();

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var outcome = parseInt($('input').val());
spinWheel(outcome);
  });
});

function initWheel(){
    var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
    row = "";
  
  row += "<div class='row'>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>1<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>14<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>2<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>13<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>3<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>12<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>4<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card green'>0<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>11<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>5<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>10<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>6<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>9<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card red'>7<\/div>";
  row += "  <div class='card black'>8<\/div>";
  row += "<\/div>";

    for(var x = 0; x < 29; x++){
    $wheel.append(row);
  }
}

function spinWheel(roll){
  var $wheel = $('.roulette-wrapper .wheel'),
        order = [0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4],
        position = order.indexOf(roll);
        
  //determine position where to land
  var rows = 12,
      card = 75 + 3 * 2,
      landingPosition = (rows * 15 * card) + (position * card);

  var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) - (75/2);

  landingPosition = landingPosition + randomize;

  var object = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) / 100,
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) / 100
    };

  $wheel.css({
        'transition-timing-function':'cubic-bezier(0,'+ object.x +','+ object.y + ',1)',
        'transition-duration':'6s',
        'transform':'translate3d(-'+landingPosition+'px, 0px, 0px)'
    });

  setTimeout(function(){
        $wheel.css({
        'transition-timing-function':'',
        'transition-duration':'',
    });

    var resetTo = -(position * card + randomize);
    $wheel.css('transform', 'translate3d('+resetTo+'px, 0px, 0px)');
  }, 6 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) warning! If your problem is reactjs related, then post the reactjs code instead of jquery one. Otherwise we might waste time on unrelated issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.